# Ras Pi 3 web server constantly "goes down" and comes back up

Tags: raspberry-pi3

When I attempt to ping or SSH into the Ras-Pi it returns with nothing. The pi generally comes back after around an hour and I have no idea why? Hosting on "Apache2"

Answer (score 0):

It probably because your power adapter cannot provide enough power, for Raspi 4B, it requires 5V--2A, hope that'll solve your problem.